# Setting SQS Destination for S3 Event Notification - Invalid S3 Resource Format

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, snowpipe

I was attempting to setup an event notification in S3 that would send a message to an SQS generated by Snowflake on any object creation event. This is fairly straightforward, but when I attempted to test the configuration, I noticed that no event had occurred. On closer inspection, I noticed this:

[image]

When clicking on the error, I get a message that the ARN has an invalid S3 resource format. I received this ARN from Snowflake so I'm sure it's valid. So, why is this error occurring and how can I get around it?